# Android XMLPullParser: Failed to Parse Html Page

Tags: android, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

Android XMLPullParser failed to parse Html String having a javaScript function, where a less than symbol is used as a if condition. 
Any other suggestions please...!

```
        String webContent = "........";
        XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        XmlPullParser myParser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();

        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream( webContent.getBytes( "utf-8" ) );
        myParser.setInput(is, null);

        int event = myParser.getEventType();
        String tableData = "";
        while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) 
        {
            String name=myParser.getName();
            Log.e(TAG, "The event name is : "+name);
            switch (event){
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                if(name.equals("table")){
                    tableData = myParser.getText();
                }
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                break;
            }        
            Log.e(TAG, "the text for tag "+name+"  is "+myParser.getText());

            event = myParser.next();

        }
```

When its trying to parse the following string for script tag, myparser.getText() returuning the text upto '<' symbol in if condition but not upto the closing tag of script

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                var txt = $("p#crt").html().replace((/[A-Za-z]|(\W)/g),"")
                if(txt < 1) {txt = 0};
                $("#crtnumber").html(txt)
                if( txt == 1 ) {$("#crttext").html(" item")}
                else {$("#crttext").html(" items")}
                $("p#crt").remove()
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Im iterating through the complete html page and im getting the exception at this function `myParser.next()` after parsing to some extinct, the following is the exception i've got: `org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: name expected (position:START_TAG <null>@253:14 in `

Comment: How we can say anything as we don't know what you are doing? You can put some code snippet or the log so that we can have some idea what is being wrong?

Comment: I've edited the question with my parsing code, have a look.

Comment: `getText()` returns `null` for a `START_TAG`. See the doumentation of one of the `next*()` methods of the `XmlPullParser`.